# JavanApplet AccesControlException access denied Permission

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, permissions, japplet

I wrote a java applet using eclipse which worked fine in eclipse. I attempted to add it to my webpage and the applet loads but stops when it starts to use the web navigating api "htmlunit." The specific error is

Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "com.google.appengine.runtime.environment" "read")

The HTML is:

```html
<applet code="abc.123.class" archive="abc123.jar" width="400" height="300"></applet>
```

I packaged it as a runnable JAR. I've spent several hours trying to find out why and what I've gathered is I may need one or all of the following.

1. Manifest File (I believe eclipse just created an automatic on)
2. JNLP File
3. Sign my applet with a key.

Comment: When editing, I made the presumption that the HTML was actually: `<applet code="abc.123.class" archive="abc123.jar" width="400" height="300"></applet>` (no spaces after the `<`).  If that is wrong, please add them back in using [another edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23159295/edit)  (and use a [validation service](validation service) to see that the HTML is wrong).

Comment: Oh, and note that I meant the **[W3C HTML validation service](http://validator.w3.org/)** there.  Oops!  ;)

Answer (score 0):

> The HTML is:

```html
<applet code="abc.123.class" archive="abc123.jar" width="400" height="300"></applet>
```

The HTML should be:

```html
<applet code="abc.123" archive="abc123.jar" width="400" height="300"></applet>
```

The `code` attribute should be the fully qualified name of the class.  E.G. for a plain Swing applet the FQN would be `javax.swing.JApplet` and the path in the `rt.jar`, or expanded on the file system the relative path would be `javax/swing/JApplet.class` (note the combination of `/` and `.`).  The way it is written in *your* example it would appear as `javax.swing.JApplet.class` which is ..neither of those two.

### Note

That explanation presumes that the applet class is called `123` and it is located in the `abc` package (which are extremely confusing and unspecific names, BTW).  If that is not the case, please fill in that information.

Comment: I don't think the HTML was the problem. The applet loads fine. The problem is the applet is supposed to parse information from another site. However, it when the applet gets to that part in the code it doesn't connect to the other site. The java console gives me the error message "Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "com.google.appengine.runtime.environment" "read")"                      How do I change the permissions to allow the applet to do this.